# Mentir à propos

Tags: traduction, locutions, constructions

J'ai cherché l'original français de la locution

> [*Is politics nothing other than the art of deliberately lying?*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/300020-is-politics-nothing-other-than-the-art-of-deliberately-lying)

attribuée à Voltaire, et je suis tombé sur

> [*La politique est-elle autre chose que l’art de mentir à propos ?*](https://www.dicocitations.com/citation_auteur_ajout/91315.php).

Vraisemblablement les deux phrases se correspondent, mais je me demande

- si *mentir à propos* est une traduction exacte / commune de *to be lying deliberately*

ou

- seulement d'un jeu de mot utilisé par Voltaire, mais qui n'a pas de sens indépendant. (C'est à dire, s'il a tronqué la construction grammaticalement correcte *mentir à propos de quelque chose*.)

J'apprécierais des explications.

Comment: I would say "deliberately" is a mistranslation. I think of "at the opportune moment"

Comment: Would *Is politics no more than the art of choosing when to lie* be a reasonable translation, or can we not understand the French sentence  that way?

Comment: @PeterShor After reading the answers I think this is a more exact translation. Though perhaps it sounds less snappy this way.

Comment: If you use the older meaning "with deliberation" rather than the more modern meaning "on purpose" for *deliberately,* then the translation means something like *Is politics nothing other than the art of choosing when to lie?* So it might not be a bad translation, just one that's been corrupted by time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La citation est exacte, la phrase n'est pas complète  puisqu'il manque le début, mais il y a bien un point après « à propos ».

> Les États tremblèrent, et se mirent à signer ; cette ruse n'était qu'un mensonge ; mais la politique est-elle autre chose que l'art de mentir à propos ? Louis XI n’avait-il pas raison quand, son ambassadeur se plaignant que les ministres du duc de Bourgogne mentaient toujours, il lui répondait : *Eh ! bête, que ne mens-tu plus qu’eux ?*

Voltaire fait référence au rôle de l'Espagne (dont il dénonce la ruse) dans les [Traités de Wesphalie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait%C3%A9s_de_Westphalie). Ce passage se trouve dans [*Les Annales de l'Empire*, Ferdinand III](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Annales_de_l%E2%80%99Empire/%C3%89dition_Garnier/Ferdinand_III).

On n'attend donc rien après « à propos ». La locution *à propos* est synonyme de « [à bon escient](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_bon_escient) », « de façon opportune » (cf. [TLF, propos, III, B](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/propos)).

À mon avis traduire « à propos » par *deliberately*, enlève quelque chose à l'idée, il y a plus dans « à propos » que dans « de façon délibérée » (ce que Voltaire aurait pu dire, mais ce n'est pas ce qu'il dit.)

---

Hors réponse :  (French Language n'est pas le lieu où proposer des traductions) si je devais traduire à propos* dans cette phrase de Voltaire je chercherais du côté de *timely* (*well-timed*), *relevant* (*with relevance*) ...

Answer (score 3):

La correspondance n'est pas directe ; "à propos" signifie "timely" ; donc, lorsque le moment se présente pour un mensonge « utile » on  ne doit pas  hésiter et  on doit (sereinement) saisir l'occasion et devenir un bon  Pionocchio, autrement dit agir *d'une manière  calculée*, ce  qui est une traduction de « deliberately ».

- (**Harrap's**) **faire qqc à propos**  do sth at the right moment
- (**Harrap's**) **deliberately**  de sang froid ; à dessein ; par calcul;  à bon escient